# Cordova: publishing Windows 10 Store app

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-universal, appx

For the last day I've been trying to publish a Windows Store app.I'm using Visual Studio 2015, latest update. My project is created with Cordova (latest update) and works fine. The build and release give no errors. But there are some issues with the package that gets created.

1) There is not appxupload file generated. I've already downloaded Cordova update 10 where they have stated that they fixed the issue. This is not the case with me.

2) The APPX file that gets created contains an ".exe" file which has the name of my package. I don't have any idea where this comes from but it gives an error when uploading the package to Windows dev center. (The package cannot contain precompiled .NET)

I' kind of stuck now because I kind find any help on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, please take a look to [this article](http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/05/06/windows-store-packaging.html) in our blog

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I was confused because I thought this was automatically fixed with Cordova update 10.